# Cannot initialize state of store

Tags: redux, redux-mock-store

I have the following code:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const initialState = { someField: {} };
const mockStore = configureMockStore();
store = mockStore(initialState);
console.log("Store is: " + JSON.stringify(store));
```

The `console.log` prints:

```
  Store is: {}
```

Why doesn't `someField` appear when printing the store?

Am I not initialising it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `JSON.stringify(store)` with `JSON.stringify(store.getState())`